# How the script can read if the classes names is the same with the id name?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id="cat1">Sample</div>
   <div class="cat1" style="display:none;">Air</div>
   <div class="cat1" style="display:none;">Sea</div>
   <div class="cat1" style="display:none;">Fire</div>
</div>
```

**Problem 1:**
    `.click` is wrong don't needed 
    because the script need read the id automaticaly
    and when readed, and see that class names below is the same
    with id name then will work properly!

**Problem 2:** This is wrong because i want use it for classes and not for id ex: `$("#cat1")`

IN A NUTSHELL! How the script can read if the classes names is the same with the id name

**Problem 1:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#cat1").click(function(){ 

            $(".cat1").show(); // <----------|  Maybe this is corect .cat1
            $("#cat1").show(); // <--|   
            $("#cat1").show(); // <--| : Problem 2

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What? I have no idea what you're (trying to?) ask of us; what is 'this' that 'is ok' (in problem 1), or 'is wrong' in (problem 2)?

Comment: I Now is difficult if you do not know

Comment: It may, or may not, be difficult but I have no idea what you're talking about or referring to. Can you explain what you want to do, or what you want to happen?

Comment: I want the script to see if the classes are the same with the id and if the same then display the classes

Comment: Just i ask what changes need to do to make this to work

Comment: Please don't be insulting to people. I made it quite clear that your question was asked badly and was (very) difficult to understand, but you made no effort to improve the question. So, while I tried to answer as best I could I still felt, and still feel, that it was unclear. This is partly due to your difficulties with the English language, and I tried to make allowance for that, but the question still needed  improvement.

Comment: @David Thomas: This is why answering a question that you've voted to close, or voting to close a question you have answered, is a bad idea :)

Comment: @BoltClock: yeah, I get that; was just trying to provide *some* assistance as best I could. But it is, sometimes, more trouble than it's worth :/

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that you want to show descendant elements that have the same class as their parents' `id` I'd suggest:

```
// selects all elements with an `id` attribute:
$('[id]').each(function(){
    // iterates over them, finds those descendants whose class is equal
    // the id of the ancestor, and shows them:
    $(this).find('.' + this.id).show();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bLtxv/).

Or if the elements are not siblings, then:

```
$('[id]').on('click', function(){
    $('.' + this.id).show();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bLtxv/1/).

To hide those elements previously shown, use a class to identify the relevant elements, select those with that class and hide them all. Then show the relevant elements, for example:

```
$('[id]').on('click', function(){
    $('.canBeToggled').hide();
    $('.' + this.id).show();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bLtxv/2/).

Comment: Thomas thnk you so mach i vote you up when i have reputation i need to ask you. Can show me an complete script because i am regardless on javascript

Comment: And how clean if is not the same?

Comment: A 'complete script' to do what? I'm not voting this question up because it was asked really badly, feel free to accept, or up-vote my answer however you see fit. What do you mean by 'how clean if is not the same'?

Comment: if the class is not the same with id how can hide? or clean

Comment: Very thenks is working perfect

Comment: How can remove the class if not the same with id?

Answer (score 1):

is this what you need?

```
<div id="cat1">click me to show .cat1</div>
<div class="cat1" style="display:none;">Air</div>
<div class="cat1" style="display:none;">Sea</div>
<div class="cat1" style="display:none;">Fire</div>


$("#cat1").click(function(){ 
  $('.'+this.id).show();
});
```

Comment: If you have a better script just post it

Comment: How can remove the class if not the same with id?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, but if they are nested into #cat1 and you want to remove element: $('#cat1').find(':not(.'+$('#cat1')[0].id+')').remove();